# Using <embed> to embed an HTML document causes large gap

Tags: html, css

My embed method is coded like that:

```
<embed type="text/html" src="header.html">
```

Now, I succeeded to embed the `header.html` file into the `index.html` but as a result I got also a weird long padding gap from the top header.

This is the `header.html` file:

```
<div class="top-main-area text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo mt5">
            <img src="img/logos/logo4.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<header class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->
                <div class="flexnav-menu-button" id="flexnav-menu-button">Menu</div>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills flexnav" id="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">
                        <!-- a couple of li here -->
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- END MAIN NAVIGATION -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6"> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="gap"></div>
```

Here is how I embed it in the `index.html`:

```
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boostrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font_awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!-- IE 8 Fallback -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body class="boxed bg-cover" style="background-image: url(img/backgrounds/wood.jpg)">


    <div class="global-wrap">

<embed type="text/html" src="header.html">
```

I tried to play with the CSS settings but i didn't succeed.
Why i keep getting that long padding gap?

Comment: There is no such general, widely supported method in pure HTML at this point.

Comment: This why i open that question

Comment: Opening this question doesn't add the desired capability to browsers.

Comment: I sucsseded embed html file to another using embed tag but i got a long gap with it. We solve that gap and we have that capability.

Comment: `<frame src=""></iframe>` ??

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to play with the CSS settings but i didn't succeed.

It is a **separate** (and invalid) document. `<embed>` is functioning as a (poorly defined) `<iframe>`.

You are missing the Doctype and the `head` element. You don't have a stylesheet in it, so you get the default margin / padding on the body element.